# HTTP Streaming on Heroku with Rails 3.1 & Unicorn

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, unicorn, http-streaming

Inspired by the [RailsCast on HTTP Streaming](http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming), I've decided to turn it on on my server. However, the `listen 3000 :tcp_nopush => false` line that Ryan suggests adding to my `unicorn.rb` doesn't play well with Heroku (they don't let you specify a port). Is streaming supported on Heroku, and how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heroku tells your application what port to listen on via the environment variable PORT. Check for this environment variable in your `unicorn.rb`.

```
port = ENV["PORT"].to_i
listen port, :tcp_nopush => false
```

Comment: Thanks :D It just hit me that the config was actually plain ruby :-/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be compatible with `Rack::Deflater`, though. My pages keep giving transfer chunked errors when Deflater is used with HTTP Streaming.

Comment: `Rack::Chunked` should precede `Rack::Deflater` in the list of middlewares.

Comment: Does anyone know a solution to the deflater issue? I've posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986150/http-streaming-in-rails-not-working-when-using-rackdeflater